# three.jsl - how to create an interactive mouse-controlled 360 image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

How can we use three.js to create an effect similar to what is visible [here](https://www.felixandpaul.com/?projects/who)?

Other solutions we've seen seem to require drag&drop to control the camera angle - we are looking to have the position of the mouse control where the camera points. For example, the mouse being in the top left corner will always point the camera at the same spot. Is there an open source implementation of this?

Comment: haven't interrogated the code of that site but it looks to be a combination of the background code from this three.js example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction and history.js combined with a jquery scroll scroll plugin. It's worth reviewing the three examples code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not complicated.

You can listen mouse position on the screen and recalculate to 0-1 XY axes:

```
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;    
}
```

after this you can calculate and set camera rotation RAD:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        //default_x = your default camera x rotation
        //default_y = your default camera y rotation
        //s = sensitivity coeficient default 1 for 360° rotation, 0.1 for smaller angle 
        camera.rotation.x = (default_x*mouse.x)*s;
        camera.rotation.y = (default_y*mouse.y)*s;
}
```

and sure, you need only to put a camera inside sphere with texture ...

Comment: Thank you - is there a way to integrate device movement at the same time, so either one works? A device-only implementation is shown here: http://richtr.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html

Comment: Yes, but you should post a new question for that